# how to add the strings

Tags: asp.net

```
 string s1Temp ="";  
string  strtemp= "resourceID like'"'+s1Temp+'"' or"
 string[] strNames = { "Joe", "Mary", "Bill", "Fred" };

            //Iterate through the items of array strNames
            for (int i = 0; i < strNames.Length; i++)
            {
              string s2  = strNames[i];
              s1Temp=s2

            }


    }
```

**how  to add the  strings  strtemp  as  loop  itetares**
 **now i need  to get the  ouput like this  iterate through all the strings**

resourceID like'"'+Joe+'"' or resourceID like'"'+Mary+'"' or resourceID like'"'+Bill+'"' or resourceID like'"'+Fred+'"' or

thank you

Comment: If this is a part of an SQL query as it seems, you should not be doing string concatenation. To avoid SQL injection you need to use parameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] strNames = { "Joe", "Mary", "Bill", "Fred" };
string  strtemp= "resourceID like '" + String.Join("' or resourceId like '", strNames) + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join` takes a delimiter and a string array, and inserts the delimiter between each item in the array. This would give you `Joe','Mary','Bill','Fred`. The last line adds the initial and the final single quotes.

```
string[] strNames = { "Joe", "Mary", "Bill", "Fred" };

string s1Temp = String.Join("','", strNames);
s1Temp = String.Format("'{0}'", s1Temp);
```